# Is this integral correctly calculated?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

The problem is that I can't use wolframalpha to check this because he is worried about integration limits: I have $a>0$ and $t \in (-1,1).$

$$(1-t)^{\frac{a}{2}} \int_0^t \frac{1}{(1-x)^{a+1} }dx= \frac{1}{a} \left( \frac{1}{(1-t)^{\frac{a}{2}}} -(1-t)^{\frac{a}{2}} \right)$$

Comment: I think it is not. Look below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.
$$\begin{align}(1-t)^{\frac a2}\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{(1-x)^{a+1}}dx&=(1-t)^{\frac a2}\left[\frac{(1-x)^{-a}}{a}\right]_{0}^{t}\\&=(1-t)^{\frac a2}\left(\frac{(1-t)^{-a}}{a}-\frac{1}{a}\right)\\&=\frac{1}{a}\left(\frac{1}{(1-t)^{\frac a2}}-(1-t)^{\frac a2}\right)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{dx}{(1-x)^{\alpha+1}}=-\int -(1-x)^{-1-\alpha}dx=-\frac{(1-x)^{-\alpha}}{-\alpha}+C=\frac{(1-x)^{-\alpha}}{\alpha}+C$$

Comment: What does this prove exactly?

Comment: @Dylan This proves *exactly* what the primitive of the function in the question's integral is and how it can easily be calculated. From here it is easy to calculate the definite integral given and check whether the result obtained is correct or not. BTW, it was **not** unitl the OP changed,  long minutes after the original post, the question's data. This is why I wrote as comment below the question what I did.

Comment: I see, didn't know the question was changed. Sorry for the tone.